# How to use std::future in the proper way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

I'm new with multithreading, and i'm practicing on a little project, but i can't figure out what am i doing wrong. I'd like to check if multiple graphs are connected or not, each with another thread. I have a class Graph using DFS, which can decide it already but not in a multithreaded way. The graphs come from a .txt file, and i fill a vector with them. Here's my code:

```
bool IsConnected(Graph gr)
{
    bool visited[gr.graphMap.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<gr.graphMap.size(); i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    gr.DFSUtil(gr.graphMap.begin()->first, visited);
    for(int i=0; i<gr.graphMap.size(); i++)
        if (visited[i] == false)
            return false;

    return true;
}

//...now we're in main()
vector<Graph> graphs;

//n = the number of graphs in the vector
vector<future<bool>> results;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    results.push_back(async(launch::async, IsConnected, graphs[i]));
```

When i try to compile it i get an around 50 line length error message, the only thing i can understand from it is that "invalid use of incomplete type future..." but i don't know what's the problem, i just tried to imitate what i've seen in some tutorials about async future. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you include its header?

Comment: Yes, i started with that before even writing the future section! :)

Comment: `bool visited[gr.graphMap.size()];` is not allowed in Standard C++ , array dimensions must be known at compile-time. I guess trying to pass this thing to a function is causing your errors. to get better help you will need to show the definition of `DFSUtil`  (preferably post a MCVE)

Comment: Def. of DFSUtil: void Graph::DFSUtil(string v, bool visited[]); First it calculates v's "index" in the map with the help of iterators.Then changes the given bool visited[index] element to true. Then i loop through the list<Vertex*> in which i keep the related vertices of v, i calculate their indexes in the map the same way, and check if they were visited before. If not, then i recursively call DFSUtil((*list)->name, visited).

Comment: Well my problem was that i used GNU compiler on windows, which have a bug or something. Under Linux it works great!